# Android setOnEditorActionListener not working

Tags: android, events, android-edittext

for some reason  the setOnEditorActionListener is not working.

Im on the target sdk of 22.

Here is the code inside my onCreate Method:

```
final EditText pageBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pageBox);

    searchBox.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {

        }
      }
    });
```

And here is the xml:

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/searchBox"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:hint="@string/string_find_player"
   android:layout_gravity="left"
   android:layout_weight="1" />
```

All Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you see the "next" button on your keyboard. Did you try to debug if the code enters the onEditorAction method? My guess is that you are looking at the wrong keycode

Comment: try returning true..and also add the IME action described by the answer by roarster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try adding `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` to your xml since you're looking for that code (`EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE`):

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/searchBox"
android:singleLine="true"
android:hint="@string/string_find_player"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

Comment: singleLine was the key for me here.

Answer (score 0):

What object is **searchBox**, maybe you have to add listener to **pageBox**